Couldn't connect to server when using Elasticsearch
When using Localhost it's working fine
root@ip-172-16-0-102:/home/ubuntu# curl localhost:9200
{   
  "name" : "ip-172-16-0-102",   
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",  
  "cluster_uuid" : "xXGFhvjvR_qbJK_oC0YPSg",  
  "version" : {    
  "number" : "8.13.4",   
  "build_flavor" : "default",     
  "build_type" : "deb",     
  "build_hash" : "da95df118650b55a500dcc181889ac35c6d8da7c",     
  "build_date" : "2024-05-06T22:04:45.107454559Z",     
  "build_snapshot" : false,     
  "lucene_version" : "9.10.0",    
  "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",     
  "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"   },   
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search" 
}

root@ip-172-16-0-102:/home/ubuntu# curl xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 9200 after 2 ms: Couldn't connect to server

My Config File: elasticsearch.yml

Please share the full logs.

How to get the log @dadoonet

Hey Akila, can you also share cat grep -v ^# elasticsearch.yml. About log path, the default logs path is /var/log/elasticsearch.


Check Local Firewall:

sudo ufw allow 9200/tcp
sudo ufw reload


Add AWS/Azure Security Groups

AWS -> EC2 -> Security Groups -> Add an inbound rule for port 9200 with the appropriate source - allow all

Test from a Remote Machine:

curl http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200
telnet xx.xxx.xxx.xxx 9200


Elasticsearch Logs

 sudo tail -f /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log

